# Work with Vuforia SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I currently work with an augmented reality project but i develop my application with Unity and Vuforia, but i think that the correct is develop my application with Android Studio and Vuforia because my application is native for Android, but how can i? How can import the vuforia SDK and import my models 3D and Sounds into android? 
Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You can make an android project with your existing Unity application. In Unity, go to File> Build Settings, then check "google android project". After building it, you can import that project into Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

[how to add vuforia to Android Studio](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/using-android-studio-vuforia)
To import your models to vuforia there are some options but if you want your models to animate(maybe even to play some sounds) you need to use a 3D engine like JPCT, jMonkeyEngie. [See this 3D engine list](https://android-arsenal.com/free)
Currently I'm trying to integrate Vuforia with jPCT with no success yet